# hashable hashValue to hash(into:) for a CGPoint

Tags: swift, hashtable

I have a Swift class that sets up an anchor with Point and conforms to Hashable using hashValue. I need to update my class to conform to the new protocol but am lost as to how to change hashValue to its new protocol method.

```
class MyClass {

    var center: Point

    var x: Double {
       get { return center.x }
       set { center.x = newValue }
    }
    var y: Double {
       get { return center.y }
       set { center.y = newValue }
    }
}

extension MyClass: Hashable {
   var hashValue: Int {
      return x.hashValue ^ y.hashValue
   }
}
```

I know I need to use:

```
func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher {
   
}
```

I've tried hasher.combine() but I don't know how to use it with x.hashValue and y.hashValue or if there's something else I need to use. Please help.

Comment: Read this: https://nshipster.com/hashable/

Comment: The code doesn't compile even if `Point` is declared somewhere

Comment: Funny enough, code like `return x.hashValue ^ y.hashValue` is exactly why `hash(into:)` was introduced. `^` is a terrible way to hash `x` and `y` together, because the collisions are so predicable. Every point `(0,0), (1, 1), (2, 2), ...` all hash to the same value.

Comment: Thanks for the info @Alexander-ReinstateMonica. That's interesting. I haven't done anything with Hashable before so it's nice to have a little background. And yes, the code does compile, I only posted the relevant parts. Thanks again.

Comment: IDK what `Point` is (is it an alias to `CGPoint`?), but wrapping it in a class is probably a bad idea. Assuming the original `Point` is just a `struct` containing to `Double`s (each 8 bytes), it would have had a size of 16 bytes. By wrapping it in a class, on 64-bit systems, you've introduced another 16 bytes of overhead, plus the overhead of allocation, ARC memory management, and de-allocation. You should use a `struct` instead, or perhaps just write an extension on `Point` direction: `extension Point: Hashable { ... }`